# How to make a program for different screens on android

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, android-studio

I am developing an app for cellphones and tablets, the thing is that I need that the app run on devices 2.3.3 android version ( I think API level 10) which most of this devices use a screen of 2.7 inches, so I try to fit the app to this screens and to 4 inches screen, the thing now is for tablets... The app is really simple, I just use a TableLayout inside a scrollview with some TextViews and Edittexts; for smallest screens it visualize fine, but in tablets it seems not good, half of the screen is wasted, well I just want that the textviews and Edittext take the whole screen... I put on the manifest that the application is only on portrait mode. Also, I am using android studio... here is the xml of the activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:background="@drawable/logixbackground">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context=".GPSActivity"
        >

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="@string/txvwTittle"
                android:id="@+id/txtVwTitulo"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textColor="#c61d11"
                android:inputType="none"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="@string/tv_velocimetro"
                android:id="@+id/txtVwVelocimetro"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="20dp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="38dp"
                    android:id="@+id/edTxtVelocidad"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:inputType="none"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:editable="false"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:background="@drawable/abc_ab_transparent_dark_holo"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="#c61d11"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="140dp"
                    android:layout_height="38dp"
                    android:id="@+id/edTxtVelMedida"
                    android:inputType="none"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:editable="false"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:background="@drawable/abc_ab_transparent_dark_holo"
                    android:textColor="#c61d11"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

            </TableRow>

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/tv_brujula"
                android:id="@+id/txtVwBrujula"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:inputType="none"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TableRow>

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="38dp"
                    android:id="@+id/edTxtBrujula"
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:inputType="none|number"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:background="@drawable/abc_ab_transparent_dark_holo"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="#c61d11"/>

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="140dp"
                    android:layout_height="38dp"
                    android:id="@+id/edTxtBrujdireccion"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:inputType="textCapCharacters|none"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:background="@drawable/abc_ab_transparent_dark_holo"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="#c61d11"/>

            </TableRow>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/tvgeopos"
                android:id="@+id/txtVwGeoPos"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:inputType="none"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="20dp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/txtvw_latitud"
                android:id="@+id/txtVwLatitud"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:inputType="none"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="18dp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="38dp"
                android:id="@+id/edTxtLatitud"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#c61d11"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:editable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:background="@drawable/abc_ab_transparent_dark_holo"
                android:inputType="number" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/txtvw_longitud"
                android:id="@+id/txtVwLongitud"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:inputType="none"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="38dp"
                android:id="@+id/edTxtLongitud"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:background="@drawable/abc_ab_transparent_dark_holo"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#c61d11"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:editable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <Button
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/btn_agregar_punto_interes"
                android:id="@+id/btnPuntoInteres"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:textSize="15dp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <Button
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/btn_ver_punto_interes"
                android:id="@+id/btnVerPuntoInteres"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="15dp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <TableRow>

                <Button
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/btn_panico"
                    android:id="@+id/btnPanico"
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:textColor="#b2000c" />

                <Button
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/btn_ir_logix"
                    android:id="@+id/btnIrLogix"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

            </TableRow>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

which is the best method to do this, or I had to make independent apps, one for tablets and one for cellphones?

Thanks in advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create two layouts, one is the default one which will be used by small screen cellphones, and its xml file will be in standard layout folder, the second one would be for tablets and it should be in folder layout-sw600dp.

What you should do is to copy your current cellphone optimized layout to this new folder layout-sw600dp and tweak it until it looks good on tablets.

Actually if it looks good on cellphones, you should be able to tweak it so it will look good on tablets. Its always better to stay with one layout.

Comment: Hi @marcin_j, how can I achieve this? creating the folders you said and the the layouts? thanks in advice!

Comment: Yes,this new folder you must create by yourself

Comment: and do I had to specify on the manifest or in the code something about that new layout folder?

Comment: No just create folder

Answer (score 1):

I think you should probably start by [reading the documents](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html) which spell out pretty clearly what you should be doing.

Failing that, the tl;dr version is you can have multiple layouts for the same `Activity`/`Fragment` - one for small screen sizes and one for large.

Comment: Hi @panini thanks for the quick reply...I read the documentation, but my english is not to good, the thing in my app is that I use in some parts the 2 edittext, how can I enlarge this and 1 take the half of the screen and the other the other half...? because as you can see I use 150dp for layout_width

Answer (score 1):

Go through this content.You will get better idea about it.

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps, but I noticed in the graphical layout if you use Android Studio, it has an option to make a Landscape layout.  It's in a dropdown on left side of window that has the Design tab of the xml layout.  First option in dropdown is "Create Landscape Variation".  Hope that helps.  Although you might still have to redesign for the wider screen.